# fbx export Bone_end

Tags: armature

When I export an armature as fbx and reimport it blender automatically adds a bone at the end and adds an "_end" to the bone name. Do these bones have a purpose?

So far I have considered them a minor nuisance and simply deleted them. Here is what happened when I reimported the Armature three times

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In many other software packages (e.g. maya) and in the fbx format there are *joints* instead of bones. A joint (point position) has a location, orientation, size but no length. Blender's bones naturally have a length since they actually are two connected joints. In reality you don't really need the tip of the bone to create a transformation matrix, but this is a Blender specific design decision.

So when exporting, an unconnected bone is converted into two connected joints. Two bones joints are converted to three connected joints. That way and *end* joint is automatically created to preserve the *tip* information of a bone. Even when rigging with joints it is common to create an *end joint*, since it makes orienting the last joint (before the end) easier.

Importing the rig create a bone for every joint, because the importer doesn't know if the rig uses end joints or not.

When importing a rig into Blender, there is an option to automatically remove the *end joints*: **ignore leaf bones**

[image]

In the process of animation, the leaf/end/tip joints (bones) are usually irrelevant and can be ignored or deleted.

<sup>Related: [Generic import options](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36607/30849) for fbx files by Gui de Souza.</sup>

To enable/disable the export of leaf bones, check/uncheck the option in the export options under *Armatures*.

[image: export option]

Comment: But how do I make Blender not export leaf bones?

Comment: By unchecking the *Add Leaf Bones* option in the export dialog, see my edit.

Comment: Hello, sorry to revive this but do you know of a way to set Blender not to add leafbones by default when importing rather than having to set it each time for each import?