# Is there any way to clean up/optimize mess of bones on imported model?

Tags: rigging, bones, import, .fbx

I've imported model from FBX, and there happened to be *a lot* of bones which control part of the model (face of character). This mess of bones actually makes it hard to see character itself, not to mention working with it. I tried searching to no avail, are there any quick ways to make less bones appear without loosing their functionality, or, perhaps, these bones might be optimized into some sort of rig?

(I'm new to blender, using Blender 2.82)

[image: Problematic bones on model.]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16487/bones-import-incorrectly-from-fbx-file